# string indices must be integers json file

Tags: python, json, api, data-science, exploratory-data-analysis

I was trying to grab the data from youtube using the API, hopefully, I did, but While trying to parse the file I got an error, string indices must be integers.

Following is the error which I am facing...

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-213e690c5b60> in <module>----> 1 response['items'][0]['id']['videoId']['snippet']['title']

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Actually, I was trying to grab the first video from the channel So I put `response['items'][0]`, I got that easily... but when was trying to parse the `Video_ID` and `Title` of that video I am getting this error.

However, when I am executing them separately, I am getting the output.

OUTPUT when executed separately:

```
response['items'][0]['id']['videoId']
'gzJGqML4j5k'

response['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
'Roles And Responsibilities Of An AI Engineer'
```

Output when executed together:

```
response['items'][0]['id']['videoId']['snippet']['title']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-213e690c5b60> in <module>
----> 1 response['items'][0]['id']['videoId']['snippet']['title']

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Can anyone help me out and tell me how to get this output in one single command.

Comment: Can you share the sample json?

Comment: What makes you think you can do `response['items'][0]['id']['videoId']['snippet']['title']`. You see that `response['items'][0]['id']` is a string `'gzJGqML4j5k'` and you basically do `'gzJGqML4j5k'['snippet']['title']`. Further, it is not clear what output is expected.

Comment: Yes sure...
I am sharing the first video Json script
{'kind': 'youtube#searchResult',
 'etag': 'zEAAkzvpAKSGeDxW0Y4McGc-gtA',
 'id': {'kind': 'youtube#video', 'videoId': 'gzJGqML4j5k'},
 'snippet': {'publishedAt': '2021-12-07T13:30:14Z',
  'channelId': 'UCNU_lfiiWBdtULKOw6X0Dig',
  'title': 'Roles And Responsibilities Of An AI Engineer',

Comment: what is the purpose to merge 2 statements into one single command? What exactly the output that you want from the json?

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Edit your question to include all relevant information - [mre] of your code, sample input, expected output and full traceback. Don't add important information in the comments

Comment: According to your json If you need both `videoId` and `title` of the video, it requires execution separately like you did above (i.e. `response['items'][0]['id']['videoId']` and 
`response['items'][0]['snippet']['title']`). This already made sense.

Comment: Actually what I wanted is.. I want to print the Video_ID 'gzJGqML4j5k' and Title in the same line using one command, as of now I need to write the new separate query for checking both.. So is there any way to get the values in single command..

Comment: and thanks to everyone for your instant support and guidance...:))

Comment: If you just need to print them in one single line, use `print(response['items'][0]['id']['videoId'], response['items'][0]['snippet']['title'])`. There is no way to get both values from json in one command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you get in comments - you can't get two values  from `JSON`/`dictionary` in one step.

You have to get every value separatelly and use both in one `print()`

More readable:

```
val1 = response['items'][0]['id']['videoId']
val2 = response['items'][0]['snippet']['title']

print(val1, val2)
```

The same but in one line:

```
print(response['items'][0]['id']['videoId'], response['items'][0]['snippet']['title'])
```

---

Or short version which is still readable:

```
item = response['items'][0]

print(item['id']['videoId'], item['snippet']['title'])
```

and it works with `for`-loop

```
for item in response['items']:
    print(item['id']['videoId'], item['snippet']['title'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation...

Comment: @KUNALKALKOTWAR if this resolves your problem then you can mark my answer as accepted, and few minutes later you may upvote it (if you have enought points of `reputation`)

Comment: marked as accepted.. not having enough reputation for upvote... 
BTW thanks for detail explanation...